# How can I get a URL to a submitted form?

Tags: html, forms, url

I'd like to use visualping.io to get notification when a permit has been filed with my city for a particular address. The city publishes permits but only through a POST submitted form. How can I get a GET URL for the submitted form which I can provide to visual ping? Is there a service which will provide a GET url that in turn submits the form for me?

Comment: Do you mean you are looking for a service that will take a URL and a list of parameters (key-value pairs) and send a POST request to the specified URL with those parameters on your behalf?

Comment: That's right, preferentially without my having to dig through the source code to figure out what it looks like. A quick glance at the source shows that I'll have to start reading through Javascript to see what the form ultimately looks like.

Comment: Here's the form btw: https://www.austintexas.gov/devreview/a_queryfolder_permits.jsp. I have a street address to enter and have set the end date to some point in the future, which it doesn't seem to mind. The link after clicking submit is just https://www.austintexas.gov/devreview/d_showpropertyfolderlist.jsp?clicked=searchByOther.